# compile error duplicate in c#

Tags: c#, ckeditor

I added a cheditor to my project,after that I faced with this error:

---

> Error 2   Duplicate 'AssemblyDescription'
>   attribute\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs   Error  3   Duplicate
>   'AssemblyConfiguration' attribute\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 4   Duplicate 'AssemblyCompany'
>   attribute\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs   Error  5   Duplicate
>   'AssemblyProduct' attribute\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 6   Duplicate 'AssemblyCopyright'
>   attribute\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs   Error  7   Duplicate
>   'AssemblyTrademark' attribute  \Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 8   Duplicate 'AssemblyCulture' attribute    AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 9   Duplicate 'ComVisible' attribute     \Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 10  Duplicate 'Guid' attribute   \Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Error 11  Duplicate 'AssemblyVersion' attribute
>   \Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs    Error  12  Duplicate 'AssemblyFileVersion'
>   attribute  ...\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

---

Comment: how can i solve this errors?i saw msdn doc but that couldnt help me...cause this error happened after adding ckeditor.

Comment: Just pasting your error will not help, consider adding some description.

Comment: How exactly did you add chkeditor? seems like you simply embedded all the source in your project (instead of adding it as reference)

Comment: Please read [ask], if you were asked this question, what would you need to solve it?

Comment: dear Nissim I added it as reference.my CkEditor works correctly.but when I want to build my project I encounter with this errors.

Comment: dear Hari Prasad what do you mean by description?all works that i have done was that one I told.I've just added ckeditor to my project and after that i think my project assembly files has Interference with ckeditor assembly files...this is my problem

Comment: hello guys!!!!!!!!!!!!I resolved my problem in a different way...I changed the version of my ckeditor that i installed.so all of the errors removed!I don't know why the newest version of ckeditor made this error for me...tnax any way ... :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of duplicate attributes in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. You could delete the AssemblyInfo file and compile your project again.

Comment: tanx to your responsTbut i have done before and this error apears to me:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: May be this link will be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con

Comment: this error happen to me because of deleting assembly files.I know the reason!but tanx :)