# Running a .NET 4.6 MVC application on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-8.5

I have an MVC Web API 2 application that I am running quite successfully locally within Visual Studio 2015 RC. I have also successfully published this application to an IIS 8.5 instance running on Windows Server 2012. I have installed .NET Framework 4.6 on this machine also.

The behaviour that I am getting when I try to navigate to the root of the site (http://localhost:81) is that I get a directory listing of the files in the root folder. Clearly I was expecting the routing config of the application to kick in an execute the home controller, but this is not happening.

I am a developer and it has been some time since I configured IIS, but I do remember that I had to do some fiddling with IIS (6?) to get the routing to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your application pool is running in **integrated** mode and not classic.

[image]

Comment: I made this change and get all sort of other errors which I will look into. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, what was it?  (someone else might want to know)

Comment: I was missing some components from the "Add Features" or whatever it's called on Windows Server 2012

Comment: What components where you missing? I have the same issue.