# iis 8.5 The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deploy my website online but it gives me this error

```
iis 8.5 The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

It is working on localhost. Also, if I configure my cloud settings to use cloud storage it works fine. But I am not sure what is the issue. After searching the web I added this

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

in my web.config file but still doesn't work.

My RouteConfig.cs looks like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { subdomain = new SubdomainRouteConstraint("www") },
            namespaces: new string[] { "DeltaNorgeWebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Files",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "File", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new
            {
                subdomain = new SubdomainRouteConstraint("files")
            }
        );

#if DEBUG
        // redirect localhost
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LocalhostRedirect",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index", path = "http://www.delta-norge.com" },
            constraints: new
            {
                subdomain = new SubdomainRouteConstraint("localhost")
            }
        );
#endif

    }
```

This is the link to the website

http://deltanorge.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1) enable "Directory Listing" for the web site in your IIS manager

2) set a default document for your website

Comment: any example to follow?

Comment: See this answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con

Answer (score 0):

Your localhost doesn't know which file it should serve. Use this in your web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="formpage.aspx" /> <!-- write your main page here -->
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```