# Publish asmx web service on azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asmx

I have created an `ASMX` web service. i want to publish it on azure cloud. I have tried by creating Azure Cloud Project in Solution but i got an error `Atleast One Web or Worker role is required`. Any Help?

Comment: I have tried by creating Azure Cloud Project in existing solution and then publish that Azure cloud service project and doing this did not worked(my web service was not published)

Answer (score 0):

Please add new Web role and try again.

[image]

Comment: i have added. This helped me in publishing but still unable to reach service over the internet. When i run in VS following error is raised in browser. 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.'

Comment: Please change some configuration
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="Login.aspx" />
        </files>
     </defaultDocument>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>

Comment: Set directory Brows true  <directoryBrowse enabled="true" /> and try again

Comment: I did and now when i run application this comes in browser. 'localhost - /

  6/7/2017 10:47 AM        <dir> bin
  6/7/2017 10:47 AM        <dir> obj
  6/7/2017 10:46 AM          639 packages.config
  6/7/2017 10:45 AM        <dir> Properties
  6/7/2017 10:47 AM         7372 TestRole.csproj
  6/7/2017 11:03 AM         1087 TestRole.csproj.user
  6/7/2017 12:08 PM         1990 Web.config
  6/7/2017 10:45 AM         1299 Web.Debug.config
  6/7/2017 10:45 AM         1360 Web.Release.config
  6/7/2017 10:46 AM          526 WebRole.cs
'

Comment: Please refer this i hope it will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con