# WCF hosting on IIS throwing Exception (Don't have Permission and HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

Exception:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of
>   the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for
>   this resource on the Web server.

I am learning WCF for the first time and I am trying to host it on IIS. I am a complete beginner so I might have done any silly mistakes.

**Running WCF from Visual Studio:**

I am *able to open* the WSDL document and able to browse when I run locally.

[image]

Now when I add this as a website in IIS Manager I get the exception mentioned above.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Config File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="WSHttpService.WSHttpService">
    <endpoint address="WSHttpService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WSHttpService.IWSHttpService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[image]

[image]

Microsoft is known for displaying errors which are totally misguiding. Please some one help me as I might be doing some other silly mistake.

Solution I looked into [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I had to add TWO USERS `IUSR and IIS_IUSRS` and give all the permissions
2. After making above changes I started getting a different exception

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map. Detailed Error Information

**Solution:**

Go to Control Panel -> Windows Feature turn on/off and there  apply below config.

[image]

Comment: This one is helpful specially for new developer join a existing wcf service project and their machine is still in new status. They would possible face this issue. Since by default, the window operation system doesn't included above mentioned options under WCF Services checkbox. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check. 
Make sure your IIS user account has permissions to view the folder where your code lives.

I would change the bindings to basic http until you can get IIS responding as you would expect.

Also, if your hosting in iis vs an iisExpress host, the  "add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" " will have an effect on how IIS tries to service the endpoint.

Comment: basichttpcinding is again working in localhost but not on IIS.

Comment: I have given all the permission to all the users.

Comment: Next I would remove the port number from the config to see if that allows iis to respond over port 80.

Comment: Phew! I was able to finally fix the issue. I have added the answer so that others can get help from it.