# How to solve HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error in web service project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I a new to web service project . I'm getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden whenever I debug my .asmx web service project . It says

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

to enable directory but it's not going to work . How to solve this error? Please Help? Any clue will be helpful .

**EDIT**

I added

```
    <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   </system.webServer>
```

this into web.config now I can see all the directory content but whenever I click .cs a page I get this error
**HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.**

And

when I click the .asmx project I get the parser error

**Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.**

I am debugging my project in local

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con), have you tried to google your question , or better yet , checked on stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm searching for solution in google but directory enabled =true is not going to solve my problem.

Comment: Tyring adding `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>` to your webconfig

Comment: @mahlatse not working :(