# IIS Manager in Windows 10

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10

How do you open IIS (Internet Information Services) Manager using Windows 10?

I have installed the developer preview of Windows 10 and can't seem to find IIS Manager?  It is not in Control Panel > Administrative Tools.

When I browse to the folder

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

it is empty.

I did a full search of my hard drive to find inetmgr.exe and found three copies and none of them would open, when I tried to open them it says "This App cannot Run on your PC"  To find a version of the App that works contact the publisher.

I know IIS works because I have ran local ASP.net apps through VisualStudio, but I can't seem to find any way to launch IIS Manager to do some configurations for a site.

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Did you enable IIS in Windows Features?

Comment: Follow [this msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh167503(v=nav.90).aspx#Win8) step by step. Only after I did all the steps did it work. Without this earlier, typing http://localhost/ showed up blank page. Now it is showing correctly.

Answer (score 583, accepted):

Thanks to @SLaks comment above I was able to turn on IIS and bring the manager back.

Press the Windows Key and type Windows Features, select the first entry Turn Windows Features On or Off.

Make sure the box next to IIS is checked.

[image]

If it is not checked, check it.  This might take a few minutes, but this will install everything you need to use IIS.

When it is done, IIS should have returned to Control Panel > Administrative Tools

[image]

Comment: MattyMerrix elaborated very well, I want to add that if you can see "ask me anything" box i.e. [Cortana](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/campaign-cortana/) "the intelligent software" at the taskbar then there is no need to press the windows key.[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KDieZ.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KDieZ.jpg)

Comment: I've installed IIS as shown in this solution but I still can't see IIS manager. But when I open http://localhost, it shows IIS default welcome page. What did I miss?

Comment: @iroel, use the screenshot. Go to Administrative Tools folder.

Comment: @jp2code finally I've found my IIS manager. It works by typing inetmgr in run menu also.

Comment: I want to point out that you must have Internet Explorer 11 checked in order to install IIS, i didn't have it check and i couldn't intall IIS

Comment: How about the Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core just below it - what does it do, and should I check that as well?

Comment: *Very important* Turn on IIS Management Console also in Windows Features. See the answer by Joseph Wu. I wish this was incorporated into the accepted answer.

Comment: in windows-10 you can go Administrative Tools via this path(Control Panel --> System and Security --> Administrative Tools)

Answer (score 303):

[image: Windows features, ISS Management Console]

Under the windows feature list, make sure to check the IIS Management Console 
You also need to check additional check boxes as shown below:

[image: Windows features, ISS, HTTP Features]

Comment: You may also want to add ASP.NET too while you are here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14949531/74585

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I handpicked the features to install, and did not check "IIS Management Console" box. Obviously then the MattyMetrix's answer did not hep.

Comment: The chosen answer, to install IIS, wasn't helpful, nor does it really answer the question as posed: you install it, but then can't open the IIS Manager.  IIS Management Console needs to be installed as well.  Thank you for contributing the correct answer, in a complete fashion with screenshots.

Comment: I believe, the minimal requirement to show the IIS Manager, is the feature `Internet Information Service` -> `Web Management Tools` -> `IIS Management Console` only. Other than that, you would of course still need to enable your `World Wide Web Services` by choosing a small set of its options - I chose `Static Content` - but that is it.

Answer (score 70):

Actually you must make sure that the IIS Management Console feature is explicitly checked. On my win 10 pro I had to do it manually, checking the root only was not enough!

Comment: Thanks. This is the one I was missing.. :) @attmik

Answer (score 43):

@user1664035 & @Attila Mika's suggestion worked. You have to navigate to Control Panel -> Programs And Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off. And refer to the screenshot. You should check IIS Management console.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 26):

- Run appwiz.cpl - brings up Programs and Features
- Choose "Turn Windows Features On/Off"
- Select the IIS Services you need

Answer (score 19):

after turning IIS on (by going to Windows Features On/Off) type **inetmgr** in search bar or run

Answer (score 18):

To install the IIS Management Console under Windows 10 using Powershell with RSAT installed:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole -All
```

Credit and thanks to Mikhail's comment above.

Answer (score 5):

It most likely means that IIS Management Console was not installed, and modern Windows administrator/IT pro should be able to quickly check this by issuing this command:

```powershell
Get-WindowsFeature *Web*
```

And if it is missing just quickly add this via the following command:

```powershell
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Console
```

GUI options mentioned above are also valid (see answer from @Joe Wu) but PowerShell it is best way to do IT for IT Pro or let's put it as "if you have to do this slightly more often than once a year" :)

Comment: Not Work on Windows 10 (Powershell 2) :(

Comment: @tuantm Install RSAT to get this command - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520 or use Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature instead. I.e. issue the following command: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole -All

Answer (score 3):

Press the Windows Key and type Windows Features, select the first entry Turn Windows Features On or Off.

Make sure the box next to IIS is checked. You good to go.

Comment: this is liteally copied from my post above

Comment: Thanks to @SLaks comment above I was able to turn on IIS and bring the manager back.

Press the Windows Key and type Windows Features, select the first entry Turn Windows Features On or Off.

Make sure the box next to IIS is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Launch **Windows Features On/Off** and select your IIS options for installation.

For custom site configuration, ensure **IIS Management Console** is marked for installation under **Web Management Tools**.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here because I was having the same issue.

If you are here and everything above didn't work, it's likely that you butchered your path somehow.

Go to `System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Machine or User` and add the following entry to the end, or append to the existing, separating with a semi-colon:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
```

After **closing and opening your shell**, you should now be able to access *inetmgr* from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for edit https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714589/patriciu-nista

Comment: What does it mean, "after closing and opening your shell"?

Comment: If you have `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` running (shells/terminal windows) close those first and reopen to refresh your environment.  Or simply restart your computer.

Comment: To which variable do I need to add this? PATH?