# localhost works but IIS Manager won't open on Window10 even after everything has been turned on in Install Programs and Features

Tags: windows-10, iis-manager

I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901434/iis-manager-in-windows-10) to turn **Internet Information Services** on in `Install Windows Programs and Features`, along with **Web Management Tools** and **World Wide Web Services**, and the items in the expando list below each of them.

`http://localhost` opens the welcome page correctly in the browser.

Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager appears in the Administrative Tools list in Control Panel.

But  no window opens when I try to open IIS Manager from the Search menu.

I can see an IIS icon in the task bar, but when I click on it, **the faint ghost of a window rises up from the grave on my left monitor and disappears off the left edge of that screen.**

EDIT: Aha! Told the thumbnail in the task bar to "maximize" and now it is visible. But the window cannot be sized. It minimizes when you attempt to size it.

Answer (score 3):

Check for an IIS Manager icon in the task bar.

If there is one, click on it to open the thumbnail and then right-click on the thumbnail and maximize the window.

On my system the window cannot be resized; it is either maximized or minimized.

Comment: Thank you!! This was driving me crazy. All of the sudden one day the IIS manager window would not come up. I think I may have had the window maximized on a large external monitor last and this time was just opening it up on my laptop screen, so maybe that caused the issue.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank Tim!