# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - published Code of Asp.net MVC-4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an application - Asp.net mvc4 with entity framework and sql server 2008R2.

I published and uploaded it to the live server, but when I open the website, it gives this error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

sometimes, i have paste this line in web.config file, but it gives me error like this:                                                                                                                Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Check that the AppPool is set to proper .NET framework version.  Check that MVC is actually installed on the server.  Here's post with details on those items and some other things you might try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte

Comment: I have checked, AppPool ise set proper, .Net Framework version is fine. we have put many application on this server, But error recognize only in this project.