# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden(iWin Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 / MVC4 / .Net 4.5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a MVC 4 Application in VS2010 and and hosted in my computer(iis7) working fine ..but when i host published code in Win Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 / MVC4 / .Net 4.5 dedicated server i got   “HTTP Error 403.14 – Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory” i'm stuck in this last 2 week.please help

it is related to mvc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte)

Comment: i checked above answers in your link(@davidG) none of this solved me...

Comment: i recreated apllication..that solved me